# Windows System, Application logs vs. "Applications and Services" logs in Event Viewer

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, eventviewer

[image]

Do Error and Warning events from the Microsoft "Applications and Services Logs" get sent to the Windows Application and/or System logs?  For example, if AppHost generated an Error event, would it show up in Application and/or System?  Is there a way to configure certain specific Applications and Services to send errors to Application or System?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are different log files on the disk. You can right-click on a log file -> Properties, and Windows will show you the file location.

The only thing you can do is create a "Custom View" (at the top of your screenshot) and select the events to be shown in your custom view.